# Trying to cout a string filled in like an array of chars but it's only cout'ing the first char in the string

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio

In my project I am reading in an assembly file (small for now just for testing). I want to see if what I'm reading is a label or not (I believe my code for that is fine). If it is a label I go through and get the entire name of the label character by character and assign it to a string index by index so that I can get the full name of the label for later use. For some reason when I cout my label it is just giving me the first character instead of the whole string. I believe the problem is at the line "cout << label << endl;". To be more specific, the first line in my .asm file has a label of A1, so when I cout label I should get A1, but I'm only getting A. Any advice on how I would fix that given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int counter = 0;
    char x = ' ';
    string myFileString = " ";
    string label = " ";

    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "Error: Not enough arguments in the command line!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        ifstream myFile(argv[1]);

        if (!(myFile.is_open())) {
            cout << "Error: Could not open the file!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            while (!(myFile.eof())) {
                getline(myFile, myFileString);

                // Does not have a label
                if (myFileString[0] == ' ') {
                    cout << "No label here!" << endl;
                }
                // Has a label
                else {
                    while (myFileString[counter] != ' ') {
                        label[counter] = myFileString[counter];
                        counter++;
                    }
                    cout << label << endl;
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my logic to use a stringstream instead. This provides a much better and more efficient way of solving my problem!

```
if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "Error: Not enough arguments in the command line!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        ifstream myFile(argv[1]);

        if (!(myFile.is_open())) {
            cout << "Error: Could not open the file!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            while (!(myFile.eof())) {
                getline(myFile, line);
                stringstream myStream(line);

                while (myStream >> word) {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your `label` with a `" "`, which results in a string of length `1`, and as a result the assignment `label[counter] = myFileString[counter]` works only in case `counter` is `0`. Try appending a character to your `label`, but first you need to initialize it with `""`. Try something like:

```
...
string label = "";
...
label += myFileString[counter];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Maksim! When I try to change the assignment to string label = ""; without the space in between the quotes my Visual Studio pitches a fit for some reason. Instead I changed my logic to use a stringstream! This made my entire program easier, I think I was just trying to do it the hard way at first :/ Thanks again!